# Trying Matplotlib animation but MatplotlibDeprecationWarning is occur

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to create live data plot. This is my script:

```
import time
import serial
import comport as com
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def animate(i, dataList, ser):
    arduinoData_string = ser.readline().decode('ascii')  # Decode receive Arduino data as a formatted string
    # print(i)                                           # 'i' is a incrementing variable based upon frames = x argument

    try:
        arduinoData_float = float(arduinoData_string)  # Convert to float
        dataList.append(arduinoData_float)  # Add to the list holding the fixed number of points to animate

    except:  # Pass if data point is bad
        pass

    dataList = dataList[-50:]  # Fix the list size so that the animation plot 'window' is x number of points

    ax.clear()  # Clear last data frame
    ax.plot(dataList)  # Plot new data frame

    ax.set_ylim([0, 1200])  # Set Y axis limit of plot
    ax.set_title("Arduino Data")  # Set title of figure
    ax.set_ylabel("Value")  # Set title of y axis


dataList = []  # Create empty list variable for later use

fig = plt.gcf()  # Create Matplotlib plots fig is the 'higher level' plot window
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # Add subplot to main fig window

ser = com.ini('COM2')
time.sleep(2)  # Time delay for Arduino Serial initialization

# Matplotlib Animation Fuction that takes takes care of real time plot.
# Note that 'fargs' parameter is where we pass in our dataList and Serial object.
# ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, fargs=(dataList, ser), interval=100)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=100, fargs=(dataList, ser), interval=100)

plt.show()  # Keep Matplotlib plot persistent on screen until it is closed
ser.close()
```

When I try to run it, I got this message: `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for FigureCanvases without a required_interactive_framework attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.`.

I'm using latest PyCharm version just to be sure the right default backend is used. Matplotlib version is 3.7.1.

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've switched the animation backend. By default on Windows 10 in PyCharm, matplotlib uses `module://backend_interagg`. I switched to TkAgg backend by placing this code in the beggining of the script

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

Then I ask ChatGPT, how I can improve my code and make it works properly. So, It gives me an akward code, but it works. And now I can plot live data!